# Why is my matplotlib histogram a straight line?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a df column:

[image]

and I try to histogram it:

```
x=new_df['err_pct']
import numpy as np
plt.hist(np.asarray(x, dtype='float'), bins=1)
```

but I get a straight line. Edit: I also tried bins=50, also a straight line.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Because you only have 1 bin?

Comment: It seens like you contain only a single x,y axis values

Comment: To clarify what @DavidG means, you specify `bins=1` so what you get is 1 bin

Answer (score 2):

Because it's having bin argument as 1. Means it will try to plot every data as a single group (bin). Try to keep optimal bin size or don't pass it (matplotlib default=10 and seaborn default='auto')

Comment: Last part is wrong, the default is `10`, not an automatic determination

Comment: yes my bad, seaborn has `auto` parameter and matplotlib as default of 10